# Puppeteer js id element contains

Tags: puppeteer

I currently have selected an item in a web page with the xpath:

```
*[@id="content_gvNewLeads_tccell0_5"]/a
```

I need to get each one of these elements, there are about 200 on a page. Each id changes slightly.

I've tried this:

```
  const aLink = await page.$x('//id[contains(content_gvNewLeads_tccel)]/a')
```

I get an error any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this XPath instead:

```js
const aLink = await page.$x('//*[contains(@id,"content_gvNewLeads_tccel")]/a')
```